# Is all python modules which installed in project will be install if i use git clone of this project

Tags: git, github

Maybe this question was asked many times but i didnt found anything. I have a project which contain many python packages i pushed it in github repo using

```
git push
```

after it i cloned it from another computer after cloning it i did

```
pip3 freeze
```

But in listed packages i didn't see some of packages which i was used in my project. Here is my question is i should install all packages which i use in my project manually or here is a best practicies

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should keep the list of references in the git repo, but the actual files (binaries) for these references should not be part of the repo and the packages should be downloaded/installed after downloading source code.

In other words. Your source code should contain configuration files that say, for example that package X with version >=3.4.5 is required to run the solution, but the repo should not contain the binaries for Xv.3.4.5.

Your `.gitignore` should prevent actual binaries from being part of the repo.

*Having said that, there are cases when the binaries should be included, but these are edge cases and normally this should be avoided.*

Comment: Thank you. How i can do list of my dependencies ? Pip freeze ?

Answer (score 0):

The key concept here is, according to git **best practices** principles you do **not** want to **version control the content of the pip modules** in your repo (the same way you don not want to track binaries), **but a** description or **manifest of the required modules and the right versions**.

Talking about purely python, the simplest way to keep track of the needed package versions that your python code need to run, is to save them in a file called requirements.txt, you can run the next command:

```
pip freeze > requirements.txt
```

Once you add the file requirements.txt into your git repository, anyone who clones it, knows the required module versions needed to run your cod and they can install the dependencies by running the next command:

```
pip install -r requirements.txt
```

Is worth to mention that at this point is strongly recommended to use any of the many strategies to cope with python environments like **virtualenv**, **pyenv** and **pipenv**, that way you can isolate packages and module dependencies per environment rather than globally.